# Fetching same entity with same id but different child id nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am having a relation in my entites like one below. My data is coming like as below.

```
Id name Child_id
1  Mark   1
1  Mark   2
```

But when I am trying to get parent by passing Id 1 using where, it gives me two results both are exactly same even child is also same.

I was expecting different child here.

```
Class Parent 
{
int Id {get;set;}
string name {get;set;}
Child Child {get;set;}
}

Class Child
{
int Id {get;set;}
string name {get;set;}

}
```

Comment: Please post your Fluent Mapping code

Answer (score 0):

I would call such data broken since it tells different truths about the same Object (with Id 1)

### Cause:

The session maintains reference euqality so when you receive the same Id from the database it will hand you the same reference. So when you get the data above NHibernate will convert the first to a Parent object and on the second line sees the same Id and hands back the same reference.

### Possible Fixes:

- Use a StatelessSession then the objects are returned as is without referenceEuqality
- make the data returned more sane
- use QueryOver and resultTransformer or Linq to Project directly into a Parent object (no tracked entity)